# Why do I get a 404 on this REST tutorial?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I've been following along on this REST tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

I've worked with REST before but not from the ground up and not using Tomcat, so I thought I'd start from the beginning and go from thee. Thing is I'm just getting a 404 when it comes to step 6.4 on this tutorial.

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the resource seems to be getting detected by Tomcat upon startup:

```
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RAGRest' did not find a matching property.
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 337 ms
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  de.vogella.jersey.first
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class de.vogella.jersey.first.Hello
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
09/08/2014 9:35:47 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
09/08/2014 9:35:48 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
09/08/2014 9:35:48 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
09/08/2014 9:35:48 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/9  config=null
09/08/2014 9:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 956 ms
```

And tomcat is up and running at localhost:8080 as proved by visiting it in the browser. Yet when I hit `http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello` all I get is a 404.

Am I missing something that is just blatantly obvious? I must be...

In case it matters, this is running tomcat 6 in Eclipse Helios on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: The reason you get a 404 is because you follow these internet tutorials. They are filled with errors because the authors throw them together and never update them. You need to read docs and buy books so you understand what is actually going on.

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep I dont think it is fair to categorize the typically high quality, free and informative resources of Lars in this way. (Also it does look like the tutorial should spent more time on explaining web app deployment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL part "de.vogella.jersey.first" needs to be the name of your WAR deployment unit (or web container specific methods like `jboss-web.xml` or Tomcat `context.xml`).

At least for normal web-apps this is the case, don't know why the tutorial speaks about the display-name.

Comment: Thanks! You've helped me solve my problem. Basically rather than accessing http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello I needed to access http://localhost:8080/ECLIPSE_PROJECT_NAME/rest/hello and bam, it worked.

Some people may feel that these tutorials are a waste of space and those who take them deserve to fail, but I have found it insightful as to a number of the basics that I didn't wholly pick up when maintaining an existing pre-built REST system. Thanks.